# How to match two arrays by adding NaNs to the smaller array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, sorting, nan

I have to plot a set of arrays. However, the way I produce these arrays is meaningful. For example,

```
x = np.array([2, 4, 5])
y = np.array([14, 15, NaN, NaN, NaN, 16, NaN])
```

But I need to modify *x* into this format: `np.array([2, 4, NaN, NaN, NaN, 5, NaN])` before being able to plot them. Since I have a considerable amount of such cases with the second array containing NaNs in arbitrary places, I would like to know what is the fastest way to convert x into y format by adding necessary NaNs.

thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `numpy.resize`:

```
np.resize(x, y.shape[0])*(y/y)
```

Output:

```
array([ 2.,  4., nan, nan, nan,  5., nan])
```

Explanation:

- `numpy.resize`: repeats input array (`x`) to match length of target `y` (i.e. `y.shape[0]`)
- `y/y`: yields 1 (`int`/`int`) or `np.nan` (anything/`np.nan`) to make a mapping array.
- `resized_arr * (y/y)`: Basically extract number from resized `x` where it can. Since multiplying any number with `nan` yields `nan`, this step makes sure that the final array has `nan` where necessary and otherwise grab from `x`.

Comment: This is a nice solution. can you please explain a little about how that code worked?

Comment: Yes, Rishav is right. I need some explanation as it seems this is really the shortest by far.

Comment: @Rishav I've added some insight. Do let me know if anything is unclear ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about this, not pretty but does the job.

```
def add_nans(x,y):
    lst = []
    index = 0
    for val in y:
        if np.isnan(val):
            lst.append(np.nan)
        else:
            lst.append(x[index])
            index +=1

    return np.array(lst)

x = np.array([2, 4, 5])
y = np.array([14, 15, NaN, NaN, NaN, 16, NaN])  

x_changed = add_nans(x,y)
```